# Java Sockets With Continuous Communication

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, javax.imageio

I want to be able to do the following on the client side:

- Open socket
- Send Data
- Wait
- Send More Data

And server side:

- Open msocket
- Recive data
- Wait
- Keep recivieng (Loop over and over)

Currently i cant make it loop :(

I have client side:

Constctor:

```
s = new Socket(ServerIPAddr, 6100);
out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
```

Looping function:

```
    public void sendImage(BufferedImage image){

    System.out.println("Starting to send");
    try {

        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", out);
        System.out.println("Sent");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // png is lossless

}
```

This can be called many times one after another.

Server side i have consturctor:

```
    public ServerConnectionThread(Socket clientSocket) {current = clientSocket;}
```

Run function:

```
    public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Connection accepted");
    System.out.println("Threaded spanwed");
    try {ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(current.getInputStream());
        while (capturing) {
            ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(in), "PNG", new File("test" + i++
                    + ".png"));
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Does anyone know why it only works for the first piece of data sent? And refuses to continuosuly sending?

-UPDATE-

```
while (capturing) {
            BufferedImage b = ImageIO.read(in);
            if(b == null){
                continue;
            }
            ImageIO.write(b, "PNG", new File("test" + i++
                    + ".png"));

        }
```

Seems to fix this issue

Comment: Why are you using an ObjectOutputStream when you aren't writing objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are closing inputStream ?

Try this -

```
 while (capturing) {
            ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(in), "PNG", new File("test" + i++ ".png"));
            //in.close();
      }
```

Comment: while (capturing) {
    ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(in), "PNG", new File("test" + i++
      + ".png"));

   }

After the first image is sent it seems to say:

Comment: The iamge is null which is annoying.

Comment: Is this because it is looping to fast? Is there anyway to make it wait until it has data?